# Stop User From Liking Post Multiple Times

Tags: php, mysql

I have a like button, which allows users to like posts on my site. If the user likes a post they have not liked before it will +1, if they press the same like button again it will -1. This is working on my virtual server on my laptop. However, the same code is not working on my live site. On my live site the user is able to like the same post multiple times, which is not what I want. I'm using a JQuery Ajax call to a PHP file that fires a some MySQL code.

Can anyone see anything obviously wrong with the PHP below?

```
include ("../con/config.php");

$postid = $_POST['postid'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];

$query = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS CntPost FROM Likes WHERE UserID = ? AND PostID = ?");
$query->bind_param('ss',$userid,$postid);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$fetchdata = $result->fetch_assoc();
$count = $fetchdata['CntPost'];

if($count == 0){

     $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO Likes(UserID,PostID) VALUES(?,?)");
     $stmt->bind_param("ss", $userid, $postid);
     $stmt->execute();

} else {

     $stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM Likes WHERE UserID = ? AND PostID = ?");
     $stmt->bind_param("ss", $userid, $postid);
     $stmt->execute();
}

// count numbers of likes in post

$query = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS CntLike FROM Likes WHERE PostID = ?");
$query->bind_param('s', $postid);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$fetchlikes = $result->fetch_assoc();
$totalLikes = $fetchlikes['CntLike'];

$return_arr = array("likes"=>$totalLikes,"type"=>$count);

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: Just set a unique index on the relevant columns

Comment: @Strawberry thank you. Would that then create an error when the user tried to like the post more than once? Do you have an example of the code one would use? Thanks again.

Comment: yes it would not insertr a new row and as you don't check for affected rows, it would change a thing for you

Comment: @nbk sorry I didn't get the last bit of your sentence. Can you explain what you mean? Thank you.

Comment: when you try to add a identical value to a UNIQUE column you get an error from mysqk server. But inb your code you don't check for errors, so you will not notice it.

Comment: @nbk thanks. I would like the user to be able to like a post, but if they have made a mistake or change their mind can unlike the post, which is what my current code is trying to do. How would I work this into the unique columns approach. It seems to be my logic of saying whether a user has liked a post before that is not working.

Comment: yes i see, but you refered to that user would like a post twice, with your code the would delete their like, this happens because you can not differeciate bewtween dislike udn unlike, so you are missing a variable (Post)

Comment: My main question is why is @count coming back as 0 if the user has liked the post 1 or more times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it. The issue was in the MySQL database column itself for the UserID. The number of chars for the column was not long enough and was truncating the UserID, which I populate using the sessionID. I amended this field in the database to allow for the length of a sessionID.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps this statement
`"SELECT COUNT(*) AS CntLike FROM Likes WHERE PostID = ?"` need UserID in WHERE statement so you would know that specific UserID in that specific PostID